# jssor slider leaving line on side and scaling when not needed

Tags: css, jssor

I am using jssor slider for a slideshow which works fine in IE11 and Firefox. However in Chrome, it leaves a dark vertical line on the right edge of some (but not all) of the images. It also, on random startups, resizes the pictures to make them too large.  The pictures are are stored at 335x260 px and the width of the slider is set at 335px. This is crazy, I don't see where the problem is coming from and I am using their code for most of it. My guess is a simple error, but I can't see it, and have been looking for literally days while doing other parts. Here is the code and the css:

```
#PhotoShow {
clear: both;
float: left;
height: 260px;
width: 335px;
display: block;
margin-left: 0;
}

<div id="PhotoShow" >
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 335px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->  
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: move;  position: absolute; width: 335px; height: 260px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div><img data-u="image" src="photos/4JoeBonamassa.jpg" </div>
        <div><img data-u="image" src="photos/4WarrenHaynes.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img data-u="image" src="photos/4JeffBeck.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img data-u="image" src="photos/4LeePomeroy.jpg"></div>
    </div>

<!-- ---------------------  -->

</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" async>
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [{$Duration:700,$Opacity:2,     $Brother:{$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2}} ]; 
        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        var startImgNumber =Math.floor((Math.random()*16)+1);
        var options = {
            $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
            $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
            $PlayInMode: 1,
            $PlayOutMode: 3},
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $DragOrientation: 1,                            
            $AutoPlayInterval: 5000,  // ADJUST!!!!
            $FillMode: 1,
            //$SlideHeight: 260,
            $LazyLoading: 2,
            //$PauseOnHover: 0,
            $StartIndex: startImgNumber,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            }
           };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();

        if (parentWidth) {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            }
          else
            {window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);}
    }
    //Scale slider after document ready
    ScaleSlider();

    //Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to check it out. Please send me your picture, thanks in advance! See my email address here http://stackoverflow.com/users/2110412/jssor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's the exact problem yet.

Please always keep 'top: 0px; left: 0px; width: ...px; height: ...px;' of the container.

And then try to set $HWA option to false.

Comment: OK, well, for what it's worth, not sure which of those two did the trick, as I did both at once, but the problem appears to have disappeared! Thank you! It's now working in Chrome the same way as IE11 and Firefox